# make a copy of a string column and cut the string based on certain value

Tags: python, string, cut

I have a DataFrame with a column with installation KKS-codes in Python.

The KKS-codes look like this:

> 1BLA43AA030
> 1BOR53AR021
> 1BHY28UI021

I want to make a new column where the string only has the relevant information. sometimes the code requires a number but it usually doesn't. The required number is given after the 3digit letter which specify the certain object. like this:

> BLA
> BOR
> BHY2

I cut the full KKS-codes  with

```
df_1['KKS'] = df_1.Object.str[1:4]
```

but for certain strings i need it to be

```
df_1['KKS'] = df_1.Object.str[1:5]
```

My if-statements don't work, please help

Comment: What if statement? You didn't post any code. Read your question and realize there is no way to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

I dont fully understand what you mean by

> The required number is given after the 3digit letter which specify the certain object.

If you can explain this further with examples I can help more. Otherwise, this is how you can apply a function to a row in a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

def test_for_four(s: str) -> bool:
    third_digit_letter = s[4]
    if third_digit_letter != "2":
        return True
    return False

def split_kks_code(s: str) -> str:
    if test_for_four(s):
        return s[1:4]
    return s[1:5]

df = pd.DataFrame([{'KKS-Code': '1BLA43AA030'},
                   {'KKS-Code': '1BOR53AR021'},
                   {'KKS-Code': '1BHY28UI021'}])

df['KKS'] = df['KKS-Code'].apply(split_kks_code)
```